# Is it possible to substring database fields?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, substring, infragistics

In vb.net, my ultragrid `DateTime2` column will not format to show just the date, no matter what code I try.

So, I was wondering, is it possible to use code to get the data from the `datetime2` field (called dateStart), and then substring it, splitting it at the space between the date and time, then just display the date part of the string in the ultragrid column?

Code used to fill grid (I'm going to paramterise this after the date problem is solved)

```
 Public Sub loadIncidents()

    sql = "1=1"
    If ugClients.Selected.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        sql &= " AND clientName = '" & ugClients.Selected.Rows(0).Cells("Account_Code").Text & "'"
    End If

    sql = "SELECT supportID, clientName, dateStart, incidentProblem, incidentSolved FROM dbo.tblIncidents WHERE " & sql & " ORDER BY [supportID] ASC;"

    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand(sql, _con)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cm)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    ugHistory.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Code for `InitializeLayout`

```
Private Sub ugHistory_InitializeLayout(sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs) Handles ugHistory.InitializeLayout

    ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("supportID").Header.Caption = "ID"
    ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("clientName").Header.Caption = "Account Code"
    ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("dateStart").Header.Caption = "Date"
    ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("incidentProblem").Header.Caption = "Problem"
    ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("incidentSolved").Header.Caption = "Solved?"

    With e.Layout.Override
        .CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect
        .AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.No
        .AllowDelete = DefaultableBoolean.False
        .AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False
        .AllowColSizing = AllowColSizing.None
        .RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.False
    End With

End Sub
```

I hope this makes sense! Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated

Comment: What code do you use to connect your database to the grid?

Comment: is the column in the DB really a Date column?

Comment: If you showed us the code you are using in the `ultraGrid_InitializeLayout` handler, perhaps we could help.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, in SQLServer the field is `datetime2`

Comment: @David Code is now added to the question

Comment: @AndrewMorton Code is now added to the question, thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with UltraGrid component, (you may tag it) but I assume there are events such as CellFormat, CellParse (in DataGridView) where you could set your cell values to the desired format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27124661/6530111) is the best solution. Use SQL Server to copy a column and its contents, drop the original, and voila.

Just bare in mind you'll need to drag the column back into the place of the original, or else saving records will become a problem, with data in the wrong columns, datatype mismatches, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use UltraGridColumn's [Format](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2016.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v16.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~Format.html) property. There is no need to manipulate your data, grid is smart enough to do this for you. Add in InitializeLayout for example this:

```
ugHistory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("dateStart").Format = "dd/M/yyyy"
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work, in the end I changed the datatype that the database was storing it as

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps cast or Format

```
Declare @dateStart DateTime = GetDate()

Select cast(@dateStart as Date)          -- Returns date of 2016-07-26
Select Format(@dateStart,'MM/dd/yyyy')   -- Returns string of 07/26/2016
```

Comment: Hi John, where would this code go, in the initializelayout subroutine?

Comment: I would assume in the SELECT statement that generates the grid.   Remove the @ to reference  your field name of dateStart so SELECT dateStart = Format(dateStart,'MM/dd/yyyy'), ... FROM ... WHERE

Comment: @joe  Sorry, I just looked at your tags again.  I ASSUMED SQL Server.  I'm sure this will help  http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/WinGrid_Formatting_Cells_Containing_Dates.html

Comment: Hi John, I've already tried this code and, for some reason, it doesn't work. That's why I wondered if SQL would work